# Best way to reference files outside directory in R

Tags: r, directory

So I use a lot of custom built functions in R which I save in the documents folder in my pc. I would like to bring these functions into my R environment (I usually use `source()`). At the moment I use the entire file path, i.e. `C:\Users\usename\documents\R functions\my_function.r` and then create a quick access shortcut link in my project directory to these functions (for easy reference in case its needed). However I was wondering if there is a better way to reference these files. By better I basically mean shorter, or a way to source the files through the quick access shortcut. An alternative to this would be to create a secondary directory so I could just type `source("&/my_function.r")` (the "&" means secondary directory). This is just a minor inconvenience I think would make life easier if resolved. What do yo think? is this unnecessary complication? Is there anyone in a similar situation as me that has any tips for easily sourcing functions?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If your `HOME` directory points to `c:/Users/username/Documents`, then `source("~/R functions/my_function.R")` should work. (I actively changed mine to be `HOME=c:/Users/r2` because that's what I use and am comfortable with in linux, which is why I think it might default to `.../Documents/`. Try `Sys.getenv("HOME")` to see what yours is set to ... and that can be the `~` in your paths.) Other than that, I don't know of any way to trick it.

Comment: If these are functions you often use, you could wrap them in a minimalistic package. Then your call would just be library("myhelpers") and you have all of them available.

Comment: Good suggestion @SteffenMoritz, that's what I use for all of my helper (but not project- or job-specific code). `devtools::install(".../path/to/r2")` every now and then when I make changes, and whenever I start a new R session, `library(r2)`.

Comment: @SteffenMoritz I like the idea of a mini package and think that is a perfect solution. If you could detail the process bellow I will be happy to mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are functions you often use, you could wrap them in a minimalistic package. Then your call would just be library("myhelpers") and you have all of them available.

Creating this package is quite easy. Assuming you use RStudio, you just:

1. Create a package: File -> New Project -> New Directory -> R Package
2. Give it the name you want e.g. "myhelpers"
3. Specify the folder it should be in

Then RStudio directly creates the package structure for you.

Now you have the package structure in your folder. It will look like this:

```
- DESCRIPTION
- man
- NAMESPACE
- R
- myhelpers.Rproj
```

You just have to put your .R files with the functions in the `R` folder. It does not matter, if the functions are in one file or in multiple files.

Then in R Studio go to the Tab "Build" and click "Install and and Restart". That's it!

Now in your other projects or R files you can just type and use all the functions you put in the R folder:

```
library("myhelpers")
var <- myfunction1(x)
```

If you later on want to edit your package functions or add new ones, you can just go to the package folder and click on `myhelpers.Rproj` and RStudio will open your package project for you. After your changes just click again `Build -> Install and and Restart` to update the package.

[Here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486488-Developing-Packages-with-RStudio) is also a short explanation with pictures. This is all you need to use your functions for yourself. The nice thing is, from there you can also go further if needed. E.g. add documentation to your functions. (then you could also have a help() page to your function).